# Masonry: How do I change the columnWidth option when a new screen width or window width is found?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-masonry

I'm basically trying to change the layout of my masonry script when the browser window OR screen width falls below a certain figure. I'd like it to respond (real-time) to when you change the browsers width but it just breaks at the moment. Also, for some reason only the script loaded first will work. I've already tested Masonry's isResizable:true option but it doesn't get the affect I want. Could anyone provide a fix? This is Masonry's page, wondering if anyone could help find a solution with regard to this page: http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/methods.html

Here's my code:

```
function checkWidth() {

  var winW = $(window).width();
  var Body = $('body');

  alert(0)

  if (screen.width >= 1225 || winW >= 1225) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

      alert(1)

      Body.css({ 'background-color':'red' }); 

      // masonry
      $(function(){

      var $container = $('#container');

      $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.box',
      gutterWidth: 8,
      columnWidth: 146
      });
    });

  });


});
}

// Start second IF statement
if (screen.width <= 1224 || winW <= 1224) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

      alert(2)

      Body.css({ 'background-color':'blue' }); 

      // masonry
      $(function(){

      var $container = $('#container');

      $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.box',
      gutterWidth: 8,
      columnWidth: 113
    });
  });

});

});

}


}
$(document).ready(checkWidth);
$(document).resize(checkWidth);
```

EDIT ===============

Updated code:

```
function checkWidth() {


 var winW = $(window).width();
 var Body = $('body');

 alert(0)

 if (screen.width >= 1225 || winW >= 1225) {


    alert(1)

    Body.css({ 'background-color':'red' }); 

    // masonry


    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
       itemSelector : '.box',
       gutterWidth: 8,
       columnWidth: 146
    });
 });

}

// Start second IF statement
if (screen.width <= 1224 || winW <= 1224) {

   alert(2)
   Body.css({ 'background-color':'blue' });

   // masonry


   var $container = $('#container');

   $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.box',
      gutterWidth: 8,
      columnWidth: 113
   });
 });

}
}

$(document).ready(checkWidth);
$(document).resize(checkWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function shouldn't add a new event listener after the window get's resized. At the moment when the user resizes the window you call your function (`$(document).resize(checkWidth);`) which then unnecessarily creates another event listener (`$(document).ready(function() {...`) which fires your code when the DOM is ready (but it should be already ready).

Try fixing that (i.e. removing that event handler and simply putting your code there).

EDIT:

You need to take out your code from your `$(document).ready(function() {` clause. Moreover you  have another DOM ready event handler shorty after (`$(function(){` == `$(document).ready(function() {`). So your code should look like this:

```
if (screen.width >= 1225 || winW >= 1225) {
    // No $(document).ready here
    alert(1)
    Body.css({ 'background-color':'red' });

    // No $(function(){ here
    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.box',
        gutterWidth: 8,
        columnWidth: 146
    });
}
```

Do the same with your second if statement.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Should I just remove the line: $(document).resize(checkWidth); ?

Comment: Cheers for that. Well i've implemented that code but it breaks completely now when I resize the browser. Layout breaks and also when I hit refresh nothing displays at all. I think its the 2nd call of the masonry plugin thats the issue now, not sure what the hell is going on to be honest. Any pointers?

Comment: `$container.imagesLoaded( function(){` seems to be creating another event handler (I don't know this plugin but the name suggests that the code will be run after the images get loaded). So there is no guarantee that code will run. What do you mean by "breaks completely"? If you use Google Chrome/Firebug, see what the console says about any errors. Also, it's difficult to read code without indentation...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7456/discussion-between-egr103-and-mmm)